# Read and split XML repeated tags in sql server

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

I have this XML

```
<Flujo>
<nodes>
<Nombre>QWERTY</Nombre>
<NombreProceso>Nodo 2</NombreProceso>
<ProcesoTipo>4</ProcesoTipo>
<SolicitudTipo>1</SolicitudTipo>
<Rol>Ejecutivo de plaza: 1</Rol>
<Rol>Supervisor de creditos: 2</Rol>
<Rol>Supervisor de tesoreria: 2</Rol>
</nodes>
</Flujo>
```

I can read it but I just get one tag. after that I would like to split each tag to get this

```
        Rol                   Permiso
 Ejecutivo de Plaza              1
 Supervisor de creditos          2
Supervisor de tesoreria          2
```

any clue?

Thanks

Comment: What sql are you trying to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using xquery path, below is the sql code to get your expected output

```
        DECLARE @xml xml
        SET @xml = 
        '<Flujo>
        <nodes>
        <Nombre>QWERTY</Nombre>
        <NombreProceso>Nodo 2</NombreProceso>
        <ProcesoTipo>4</ProcesoTipo>
        <SolicitudTipo>1</SolicitudTipo>
        <Rol>Ejecutivo de plaza: 1</Rol>
        <Rol>Supervisor de creditos: 2</Rol>
        <Rol>Supervisor de tesoreria: 2</Rol>
        </nodes>
        </Flujo>'




        SELECT  
        SUBSTRING(b.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(50)'),1,CHARINDEX(':',b.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(50)'))-1) Rol,
        SUBSTRING(b.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(50)'),CHARINDEX(':',b.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(50)'))+1,LEN(b.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(50)'))) Permiso 
        FROM @xml.nodes('/Flujo/nodes/Rol') as a(b)
```

Comment: I like your answer, but I need to handle this in SQL server 2005

Comment: Thanks, i got confused, i have updated the answer with sql query to get your expected output. please check it out